# Set focus on to a textbox in a webview in order to fill it up using EvaluateJavascriptAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-webview

I have a Webview, on my XAML, and i define the URL in my .cs equivalent of that page, I am trying to fill out a form and submit it through code, without the user clicking anything, but i am having trouble filling out some textboxes as their id's do not work, please advice on how to tackle this. thanks in advance.

Page8.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="App6.Page8">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <WebView x:Name="browser" Navigated="onNavigated" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000" />
            </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

Page8.xaml.cs

```
        void onNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs args)
        {  browser.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"document.getElementById(\"VC_OA_LOGIN_WRK_NATIONAL_ID\").value = \"14587452\";");       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By [WebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.evaluatejavascriptasync?view=xamarin-forms), you can see it returns  Task, so I guess that you are not on  the Main/UI thread, so it doesn't work.

```
 private void Webview1_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            //post your EvaluateJavaScriptAsync call to the UI message
            ...
        });

    }
```